# Laravel Select Query Accessing Returned Data

Tags: mysql, laravel, select

I've been working with Laravel for a short time, and am confused about accessing data retrieved from queries. I'm trying to save data to variable but am getting the following:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Queries tried:

```
$data = DB::table('table_1')->select('user_id', 'email')->where('email', '=', Input::get('email_address'))->get();

// also tried

$data = DB::table('table_1')->where('email', '=', Input::get('email_address'))->pluck('user_id');

// accessing data

$userID = $data->user_id;
```

Both return the same.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a little bit, `->get()` will return a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections). You **might** iterate over it as an array, but you **can** profit from methods that this class offers. [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-pluck) is one of these.

That's why `$userID = $data->user_id;` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

first() did the trick, rather than get().

```
$data = DB::table('table_1')->select('user_id', 'email')->where('email', '=', Input::get('email_address'))->first();
```